# How to make ThreadPoolTaskExecutor access request scoped bean in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have list of items to be processed seperately. So, I wanted to use Java parallel stream but threads did not able to access my request scoped bean.

I tried the below implementation:

```
 @Bean(name = "myExecutor")
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(25);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("my-thread");
        return executor;
    }
```

In my service layer, I autowired the executor:

```
@Autowired
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;
```

```
public void addOrUpdate(List<ShareholderBalanceCsvItem> itemList) {
        
        // ...

        itemList.forEach(csvItem -> taskExecutor.submit(() -> {
            log.info(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " ----------------------");
            
           // ...
           createCertificateShareEntry(processType, csvItem, certificateShareEntryDTO);
           // ...

        }));
}
```

I see 4 threads are generated correctly for 4 items in the list[image]

In `createCertificateShareEntry` method, I need to access **MessageBean** which is in request scope.

```
@Autowired
private MessageBean messageBean;

private void createCertificateShareEntry(String processType, ShareholderBalanceCsvItem csvItem, CertificateShareEntryDTO certificateShareEntryDTO) {

        // ...
            certificateShareEntryDTO.setMessageOid(messageBean.getObjId());
        // ...
}
```

**MessageBean.java**

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class MessageBean {
 // ...
}
```

I get the following exception in the line `messageBean.getObjId()`

```
Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.messageBean': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot ask for request attribute - request is not active anymore!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:383)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:675)
    at tr.com.mkk.hpks.model.MessageBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1db10d79.getObjId(<generated>)
    at tr.com.mkk.hpks.service.impl.ShareholderBalanceServiceImpl.createCertificateShareEntry(ShareholderBalanceServiceImpl.java:400)
    at tr.com.mkk.hpks.service.impl.ShareholderBalanceServiceImpl.lambda$addOrUpdate$4(ShareholderBalanceServiceImpl.java:314)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot ask for request attribute - request is not active anymore!
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.getAttribute(ServletRequestAttributes.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributesScope.get(AbstractRequestAttributesScope.java:43)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:371)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You don't nor should you. If you need the request scoped bean inside an async (background) thread you are doing the wrong things (imho).

Comment: Agree with @M.Deinum, why don't you retrieve the value from the message bean in the request thread and pass it to your thread instances when you create them.

Comment: That is the case I want to know. Is it possible without creating a task instance(imp. callable or ext. runnable)? I am looking for a way to use java's parallel stream kind of multithreading if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the Runnable interface with Context Aware like below. .

```
public class ContextAwareRunnable implements Runnable {

    final Runnable task;
    private final RequestAttributes context;

    ContextAwareRunnable(Runnable task, RequestAttributes context) {
        this.task = task;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (context != null) {
            RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(context, true);
        }

        if you have any other Spring/Hystrix managed request object then you should 
        wire those as well here. 
        
        try {
            task.run();
        } finally {
            RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes();
            close any other object you initialize in the run method. 
        }
    }
}
enter code here
```

If you are using the Java concurrency package, then you need Context Aware Callable as well like below. .

```
public class ContextAwareCallable<T> implements Callable<T> {
    private final Callable<T> task;
    private final RequestAttributes context;

    ContextAwareCallable(Callable<T> task, RequestAttributes context) {
        this.task = task;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public T call() throws Exception {
        if (context != null) {
            RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(context,true);
        }

        if you have any other Spring/Hystrix managed request object then you should 
        wire those as well here. 
            
        try {
            return task.call();
        } finally {
            RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes();
            close any other object you initialize in the call method. 
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need a Context Aware Task Executor like below. .

```
public class ContextAwareThreadPoolTaskExecutor extends ThreadPoolTaskExecutor {
    
     @Override
     public void execute(Runnable task) {
         RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();

         super.execute(new ContextAwareRunnable(task, requestAttributes));
     }

    @Override
    public <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task) {
        RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();

        return super.submit(new ContextAwareCallable<>(task, requestAttributes));
    }

    @Override
    public <T> ListenableFuture<T> submitListenable(Callable<T> task) {
        RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();

        return super.submitListenable(new ContextAwareCallable<>(task, requestAttributes));
    }
}
```

Then You have define a custom Thread Pool Executor bean like below

```
    @Bean("contextAwareThreadPoolExecutor")
    public Executor contextAwareThreadPoolExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ContextAwareThreadPoolTaskExecutor();

                executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(25);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("my-context-aware-thread");
        executor.initialize();
       

        return executor;
    }
```

In your service layer. .

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("contextAwareThreadPoolExecutor")
Executor executorService;
```

This shd work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I will definitely try to reproduce the issue and see if your solution will work.